# spring cloud three releases difference Angel, Brixton and Camden

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I see there are three product lines on spring cloud. I am a newer of spring cloud and want to add to my project, which product line should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the versions of dependencies towards the bottom of the [Spring Cloud project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/).

You'll want to use the most current version for the most part since they are all marked GA, but also make sure they are compatible with whatever else you are using in your project.

So for example if you are using Spring Boot 1.2 then go with Angel, 1.3 then Brixton, 1.4+ then Camden is probably your best bet.  Even then you can always get things working by resolving dependency conflicts yourself.

If its a brand new project, just go with Camden and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I can resolve dependency issues, does it mean that I can switch from different product lines?

Comment: Depends on the implementations you choose. For instance the Netflix apis have been a part of cloud since angel, but consul wasn't introduced until later. If you stick to the general apis then you should be ok. And moving up is typically safe but down may not be because of same reasons.